# Windows %tmp% location write problems

Tags: windows-7

I am having a problem where sometimes I cannot write to the %tmp% folder. Is it possible that a backup or anti-virus software can cause problems writing to %tmp%?

Comment: More info needed. When is it causing problems? Is it a particular software? Do you get errors? What exactly is going on?

Comment: I am attempting to write php sessions to this folder. For 1 hour I couldn't login and then all of sudden it worked without changing anything. I am guessing that there was some sort of process blocking the ability to read/write to this folder. I am not sure where to look as I am not familiar with windows that well.

Comment: Could the drive the %tmp% folder is on be almost full?

Comment: 400 gb free space

Comment: try [change path tmp and temp vars](http://www.itechtalk.com/thread3595.html) to shorter path(i.e. C:\Temp)